# download is not starting for apk expansion file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk-expansion-files

i am working on a Wikipedia app in which users will download the database .zim file as apk expansion. first i created a sample of apkexpansiontest apk and i uploaded to the google play and its start working by opening the app the download will start and will complete then.

now i came accross the problem that when i apply these expansion codes to my orignal app(Wikipedia) app and when i launched my app and now launching there is no download but the download page show me pause download message and no download or other message come..

when i select database download from menu option of my app and then nothing happens no download or no other validation or finding resources message.

Comment: The version code is the same in both apps?

Comment: yes all the things i checked many times they are correct

Comment: it even doesn't check for the validation or any thing else. on creating sample project that only contain the downloader file only it works fine but after implementing that code to my wikipedia app then no download works and show me 0mb/omb.